# How to represent reports in UML class diagram

Tags: uml, visio, class-diagram

I am working on guest house management system.
Different reports are generated on daily, weekly and monthly bases. 
for example i have room class which contains room no, rent etc.. room occupancy report in generated on weekly bases according to formula 
(room occupancy=total room occupied/total number of rooms)
how do i represent this or any other report in my class diagram or do i need to include it in my class diagram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reports are output from some other class and usually don't have behaviour of their own, hence they are typically not represented in a UML diagram.  You might have a 'ReportGenerator' or somesuch class, but the actual reports do not need to be shown.  Think about how you would diagram a system with 30-50 reports.

Reports are actually more like Use Cases, and then only if you are ready to get down into the details.  They belong as part of the interface discussion, much like designing a UI or web page.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a `RoomReport` class if you feel the need to have a concrete representation for it.  You can also have a `ReportFactory` that houses the creation of reports.

Add it to your UML if it benefits the software creation process.  You're doing it for the wrong reason if you think that purity or correctness or "it's required" is your justification for doing so.

UML is a notation for communication between software developers and stakeholders in the process, not some rigid process to be served.